# Laravel global scopes and multiple joins

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Due to need of content localization, the data of each localizable model is split into 2 tables, with base and localizable fields. So i added global scope with join for code cleaness. But now, if I'm trying to join another localized table, i'm getting this error.

```
Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "posts"
```

Trouble code:

```
$news = Post::orderIdDesc()
            ->innerJoin('organizations', 'organization','id')
            ->where('posts.organization', '=', $orgId)
            ->select('*')
            ->take(3)
            ->get();
```

returns this sql:

```
select * from "posts_uk"
  inner join "organizations" on "posts"."organization" = "organizations"."id"
  inner join "organizations_uk" on "organizations_uk"."id" = "organizations"."id"
  inner join "posts" on "posts_uk"."id" = "posts"."id"
where "posts"."organization" = 1
order by "posts_uk"."id" desc limit 3
```

As you can see, other part of Post model joined in the global scope, appends at the end of query, causing mentioned error.

Maybe there's some way to make global scope prepend it's join at the beginning, or any other resolution appliable.

Thx

Comment: I have the same issue in Laravel 5.3. How did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when upgrading to Laravel 5.3. The join on my global scope was the last join, instead of the first. Building onto Anze's answer, I added the method:

```
protected function popShiftLastJoin(Builder $builder) {
    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $join = array_pop($query->joins);
    array_unshift($query->joins, $join);
}
```

Then call the method after any join in your scope that should be joined first:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
   $builder->join(...);
   $this->popShiftLastJoin($builder);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to place the global scopes at the beginning, but you could reverse the joins manually inside your global scope. It's a bit hacky but should work:

```
public function apply($builder, $model)
{
   $builder->join(...);
   $builder->join(...);

   // remove the join clauses from the end of the query
   $query = $builder->getQuery();
   $join2 = array_pop($query->joins);
   $join1 = array_pop($query->joins);

   // and merge them back at the beginning
   $query->joins = array_merge([$join1, $join2], $query->joins);
}
```